# Link to url from citation in paper, but

Tags: urls

I am reading a paper that is doing something that I would like to impliment - so I know it's possible. When it cites a reference in the text e.g. [1] it is a hyperref, but instead of taking the reader to the references at the bottom of the document it opens internet explorer and takes you to the article source - which makes it quick and easy to glance over the abstract and close or save depending on the use of the reference.

How is this possible?

Comment: Can you provide a citation of the paper whose hyperlink capabilities you'd like to emulate? Is it a piece published in a journal, is it a working paper, or something else still? Separately, are you saying that the paper doesn't have a "normal" bibliography at all, as all citation call-outs may be pointing to various online resources?

Comment: @Mico here is a direct link to the pdf: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Terry_Guo/publication/228564282_A_Unified_Framework_for_Cognitive_Radio_Cognitive_Radar_and_Electronic_Warfare-Tutorial_Theory_and_Multi-GHz_Wideband_Testbed/links/00b4951ed74b4f156f000000/A-Unified-Framework-for-Cognitive-Radio-Cognitive-Radar-and-Electronic-Warfare-Tutorial-Theory-and-Multi-GHz-Wideband-Testbed.pdf   


The paper has a normal bibliography - but where they are cited in the text lead to the online sources.

Comment: Many thanks for providing this link. I've perused the paper a bit, and my reaction is that I don't find its citation call-outs all that well designed. It's true that if some cited publication is available online, clicking on the number takes you straight to that paper. However, if the article (or book, or whatever) is not available online, clicking on the numeric citation call-out does nothing at all -- it doesn't even take you the corresponding entry in the bibliography. I find the standard natbib/unsrtnat&hyperref setup much cleaner.

Comment: @Mico I totally agree with you - I would not do it just anything, but this is more of a report for management - so the quick feedback of the abstract is useful.